# Xen crashes when loading X

Tags: linux, xorg, xen

I installed debian-7.1.0-i386-kde then apt-get install various Xen stuff. After updating Grub I found it boots up using Xen however at the point where it tries to draw my desktop (KDE) I get a bunch of random static colors on screen and it freezes/locks up/crashes.

How do I fix this so I can boot up Xen with Debian as my host OS?

Comment: seems to me you are facing a kernel panic of some sort can you get the end of /var/log/error if you just log in tty and wgetpaste it before ruunning Xorg?

Comment: @vfbsilva which logs do you want to see? heres kern.log http://pastebin.com/6QcdiDKb search `Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset` the first is the xen fail the 2nd is non xen boot which loads X and runs fine

Comment: does xen  also provide a log?

Comment: @vfbsilva I have the following logs. I don't see a 'xen' one. If it's in a folder i'll need to boot into it to check. ---- 
alternatives.log
aptitude
auth.log
btmp
daemon.log
debug
dmesg
dmesg.0
dmesg.1.gz
dmesg.3.gz
dmesg.4.gz
dpkg.log
faillog
fontconfig.log
kdm.log
kdm.log.1
kdm.log.2.gz
kern.log
lastlog
lpr.log
mail.err
mail.info
mail.log
mail.warn
messages
pm-powersave.log
syslog
syslog.1
syslog.2.gz
user.log
wtmp
Xorg.0.log
Xorg.0.log.old

Comment: are you running graphics acceleration of some sort?

Comment: @vfbsilva: I have no clue. I didn't mess with any config after doing apt install

Comment: please post the contents of Xorg.conf

Comment: @vfbsilva: http://pastebin.com/nvJ80zMe

Comment: no errors in this log. Except the acpi error which imho is not related to the crash. Takea look here http://blog.le-vert.net/?p=24 
Also i Need xorg.conf that is xorg log :)

Comment: Sounds like your Xorg config might be broken, are you sure the system is frozen? (i.e. can you ssh into it?) I think you can run dpkg-reconfigure xorg and fix it assuming you can boot single user.

Comment: @MarkCohen: I'll try that in a few hours. It's odd it would work when I don't boot with xen

Comment: In my experience, Xen doesn't really have an Xorg/Xwin support built in, as a dom0 it mostly relies on the users using VNC to connect to the domU. In your case, it might have messed up the Xorg.conf and you would just need to regenerate it.

Comment: @MarkCohen: There doesn't seem to be a config file. I googled and it said debian seems to use the defaults and doesn't have a xorg.conf. I ran `dpkg-reconfigure xorg ` and `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` both did nothing. I ran `service kdm stop` and retried, both seem to do nothing. Then I ran `Xorg -configure` and got an error which surprised me. I'm not sure why I get an error but have no problem loading kde/debian on a fresh install w/o booting into xen. The error output of `Xorg -configure` is http://pastebin.com/JuUMLJc9

Comment: @vfbsilva: See comment ^

Comment: @acidzombie24 try to remove .Xauthority file

Comment: @vfbsilva: Didn't work. Turns out I did generate a xorg conf. I copied it to /etc/X11/ and grabbed these files from `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` http://pastebin.com/KBNXPhwJ

Comment: @MarkCohen: see comment above ^

Comment: @acidzombie24 what is the output of lspci | grep VGA ?

Comment: @vfbsilva: `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
`. I decided to try on an old laptop so i don't need to reboot this pc so often. It reports `VGA compatible controller: Advance Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS482 [Radeon Xpress 200]`

Comment: @acidzombie24 maybe related to this? http://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-users/2012-10/msg00058.html

Comment: @vfbsilva: I tried googling, where the heck am i suppose to add that line? `xen-pciback.hide=(00:02.0@4) to kernel line in grub` I am looking at grub.cfg and I have no idea what i'm suppose to write it. I'm unsure where I edit `CONFIG_XEN_*` lines but I suspect thats not the host OS for xen

Comment: @acidzombie24 no idea, a easy way to find it out is ask in ##xen at irc.freenode.org

Answer (score 0):

Xen is a hypervisor that modify the standard kernel.So many drivers can not work correctly at xen, specially graphics drivers.
   So you can only start xen at cui model.You can use command line to start virtual machines in xen server.Then you can use another machine to connect a virtual machine to use it.
   If you want use GUI model in your host,you can use qemu-kvm/virtual-box as hypervisor.Qemu-kvm/virtual-box both use standard kernel,hypervisor is only a driver on host.